# Overloading templated function, with different return types based on template parameter

Tags: c++

I have a function that takes a parameter. Sometimes it's a "raw" number, sometimes it's a number wrapped in a holder class which contains some meta-information about the number. I can differentiate between the two cases like this

```
template<class T>
struct Holder
{
};

template<class T>
void f1(T)
{
}

template<class T>
void f1(Holder<T>)
{
}
```

However, now I want to return either a raw number or a holder depending on what the user wants. I know the user will have to explicitly specify the template parameter when calling the function. That's fine, but I'd like the function to have the same name if possible. Something like this

```
template<class T>
T f1()
{
    return T();
}

template<class T>
Holder<T> f1()
{
    return T();
}
```

However, calling it as `f1<int>();` or `f1<Holder<int>>();` results in `error: ambiguous call to overloaded function`

Is this possible without changing the function name? (If not, it's not a big deal, I am just curious)

Comment: No, it's not possible. You can't overload functions on return type only.

Comment: Not a dupe, because we're talking about templates here.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the approach using SFINAE (`std::enable_if`), you can use partial specialization. Since partial specialization isn't possible with function template, it requires a bit of jumping through hoops, though:

```
template <typename T>
struct f1_specialization {
    static T f1() { ... }
};
template <typename T>
struct f1_specialization<Holder<T>> {
    static Holder<T> f1() { ... }
};
template <typename T>
T f1() { return f1_specialization<T>::f1(); }
```

Either approach may be more or less clear and they should both work.

Comment: +1, I like your solution better. I've been writing too many `enable_if`s lately.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, using `enable_if`. But it's horrible. I'll be writing this in C++11.

```
template <typename T> struct is_holder {
  static constexpr bool value = false;
};
template <typename T> struct is_holder<Holder<T>> {
  static constexpr bool value = true;
};

template <typename T,
          typename = typename std::enable_if<is_holder<T>::value>::type>
T f1() {
  // T is Holder<U>
}

template <typename T,
          typename = typename std::enable_if<!is_holder<T>::value>::type>
T f1() {
  // T is not Holder<U>
}
```

You still have to explicitly specify the template argument when you call it, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [decltype](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype).

```
    template <class T, class U>
    auto add(T t, U u) -> decltype(t + u);
```

Comment: Could you explain how this solves my problem please?

Comment: Maybe I read your question wrong, but the code I posted is an example of templating return types.