# Can I use enable_if to have two functions with same name, same arguments but different return type?

Tags: c++, templates, enable-if

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18832661/3336423), enable_if can be used to define two functions with same name, same arguments but different return type.

However, when I do this:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T,
          typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value>::type>
T f1() {
  // T double, float...
}

template <typename T,
          typename = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_floating_point<T>::value>::type>
T f1() {
  // T is something else
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    auto res1 = f1<float>();

    auto res2 = f1<int>();

    return 0;
}
```

I get an error reporting `f1` is defined twice:

```
11:3: error: redefinition of 'template<class T, class> T f1()'
5:3: note: 'template<class T, class> T f1()' previously declared here
 In function 'int main(int, char**)':
19:25: error: no matching function for call to 'f1()'
19:25: note: candidate is:
5:3: note: template<class T, class> T f1()
5:3: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
4:11: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, void>'
17:10: warning: unused variable 'res1' [-Wunused-variable]
 In instantiation of 'T f1() [with T = float; <template-parameter-1-2> = void]':
17:27:   required from here
7:1: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
```

See http://cpp.sh/3g2vy

is this supposed to work? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38215920/4342498) on the dupe shows you the least amount of change you need to make.

Comment: http://cpp.sh/45s5g

Comment: @MarekR: Thanx!